# MySQL Insert using function not working

Tags: mysql

MySQL's function to insert a row into table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION create_business(
    phone_number TEXT,
    open_time TIME,
    close_time TIME,
    est_date DATE,
    bus_desc VARCHAR(500),
    bus_name VARCHAR(30),
    off_phones VARCHAR(100),
    off_email VARCHAR(100)
) RETURNS INT(6)
BEGIN
    declare bus_id INT;   <===
    INSERT INTO business
    (
        Name,OpenTime,CloseTime,EstDate,Description,OfficialPhone,OfficialEmail
    )
     VALUES
    (
        bus_name,open_time,close_time,est_date,bus_desc,off_phones,off_email
    );     <===
    SET bus_id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
    RETURN bus_id;  
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am unable to find anything wrong and logs also not giving much information on above.

```
09:58:16    CREATE FUNCTION create_business(     phone_number TEXT,     open_time TIME,     close_time TIME,     est_date DATE,     bus_desc VARCHAR(500),     bus_name VARCHAR(30),     off_phones VARCHAR(100),     off_email VARCHAR(100) ) RETURNS INT(6) BEGIN  declare bus_id INT Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 12   0.033 sec
```

Comment: Did you define the `DELIMITER $$` before all that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems couple of issues with your function,

1. You haven't declared start DELIMITER
2. `SET bus_id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` should be changed to `SET bus_id =  LAST_INSERT_ID();

It should be something like below,

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION create_business(
    phone_number TEXT,
    open_time TIME,
    close_time TIME,
    est_date DATE,
    bus_desc VARCHAR(500),
    bus_name VARCHAR(30),
    off_phones VARCHAR(100),
    off_email VARCHAR(100)
) RETURNS INT(6)
BEGIN

    declare bus_id varchar(2);   
    INSERT INTO business
    (
        Name,OpenTime,CloseTime,EstDate,Description,OfficialPhone,OfficialEmail
    )
     VALUES
    (
        bus_name,open_time,close_time,est_date,bus_desc,off_phones,off_email
    );    
    SET bus_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() ;
    RETURN bus_id;  
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Getting some other issue. Here is log for that : `SET bus_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() ;     RETURN bus_id;   END Error Code: 1418. This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable).`

Comment: It seems like configuration issue in your case, you might have enabled `binary log` and then trying to use LAST_INSERT_ID() function. But may I now, why you want to create a procedure for insert at all? why not direct insert. I have not seen in practical life where someone use procedure for `insert`, it may be some other complex cases, not for simple `insert`. Is it for getting last `AUTO_INCREMENT` ID?

Comment: The method I have shared is the basic one. Before inserting value in this table, I have to do  some other complex stuff. Yes it is for getting last `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Didn't touch any mysql config. I have written such function in postgres, which has much easier syntax.

Comment: Actually, the change I have suggested is after executing your function in my `MySQL` server only, and interestingly it doesn't give any error. I'm less experienced on `MySQL` level configuration parameters.

Comment: Query is correct. I have not provided more information that I am running MySQL on AWS RDS.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM create_business(     '8197292812',     time('8:00:00'),     time('18:00:00'),    '2011-12-1',     'json coming',     'Punjabi Rasoi method',     '8183912389123',     'vishal@gmail.com' )` now facing issue regarding date. Log `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax`. I used `str_to_date()` also, but in vain.